# Find extrema of $y=?(x)-x$ with the Minkowski Question Mark function

Tags: proof-writing, maxima-minima, fractals, analyticity, constants

**The Goal:**

is to figure out the global extrema of the [**Minkowski Question Mark function $?(x)$**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinkowskisQuestionMarkFunction.html). Here is the graph of:
$$?(x)-x:$$
[image]

The $y$ value of the global maximum was found by systematically guessing decimal values:

$y≈0.142522$:
[image]

It turns out that:

$$?(.142522)=.0156249999…≈\frac 1{64}\implies ?(y)=\frac1{64}$$

Since $?(x)≈2^{1-\frac1x},y=\frac17$,

where the x coordinate of the maximum is the value such that:

$$?(x)-x\pm\frac17=0$$

Therefore:

$$|?(x)-x|\le\frac17:$$

[image]

and the simple bounds for the function itself:

$$x-\frac17≤?(x)≤x+\frac17:$$

[image]
but how do we prove the extrema y values? Is this the correct result?   Since this function is nondifferentiable, one cannot use a derivative test to find the maximum. Please correct me and give me feedback!

**Correction**

We have good bounds for the function, but after some iterative zooming and trials from @TheSimpliFire, we got the following result:

$$\min(?(x)-x)=\pm 0.14259056927… \text{at}\  x=0.207075196…,x_2=x_\rm{max}$$

There is the interesting result of almost $\frac1 {64}$:

$$?(0.14259056927)= 0.0156249999999999999999998347561228918792761675351652337679562248… $$

$$?(0.14259056927)-0.14259056927= -0.126965569278000000000000165243877108120723832464834766232043775… $$

$x-?(x)-0.142590569278$:

[image]

**Second Goal: Main Local Extrema:**

Even though the function’s derivatives are $0,\pm\infty$, but Wolfram Alpha plot the derivative of the function:

$$\boxed{\max(?(x)-x)=-\min(?(x)-x)\iff ?’(x)=1}:$$

[image]

Therefore the largest local maximum of $?(x)-x$ is about $(0.458211892, 0.0300691122226992386)$ and the minimum has a similar value:

[image]

We have an exact form of this maximum as the solution to of $?’(x)-1=0$, but how Wolfram Alpha plots the derivative and this new set of extrema are another problem.

$?’(x):$

[image]
We also have this plot for $?(x)$ vs $x\pm 0.0300691122226992386$. Notice the intersection:

[image]

Comment: A nice text here ; https://zims-en.kiwix.campusafrica.gos.orange.com/wikipedia_en_all_nopic/A/Minkowski's_question-mark_function

Comment: By iteratively zooming into the argmin/max, Wolfram suggests [$\pm1/7$ are non-optimal](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/886338811179716630/953207809674194975/min.png).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Please see the corrected max/min values. Could you please help find more information on them?

Comment: Mean value Theorem even though the function is not differentiable?